# How to select the first cell in a tableview without reusing it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to select the first cell in the tableview and give it an alpha of 100%, only for the first cell and this style should not be reused by the `dequeueReusableCell` method.

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
   cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0
}
```

When I use above code within the function `cellForItemAt` it will be set alpha of 1.0 to every 7th cell. I only want it to be applied on the first cell and the style should not be reused... How can I solve this? Should I create another custom cell or is there a kind approach in code do achieve this?

Comment: Instead try to update in the data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reset the imageView's alpha if it's not the first cell.

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
   cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0
}
else {
   cell.imageView.alpha = 0.0 // or whatever alpha value you need
}
```

Comment: In general, any cell property that you set for some condition must reset for all other cases.

Comment: When you start scrolling the rows jn the UiTable will be re-used. So the color from the first row is reappearing for following rows. Tip: You can also use the section header as  title!

Comment: Have some issue related to this question and answer. By default the first cell has alpha 1.0 and other 0.6 alpha. When I click another cell, I change the alpha of that cell to 1.0 by calling `didSelectItemAt` of the collection view. But I've set the first cell to 1.0 like in your solution. How to fix this, so the first cell of the collection has alpha 1.0 until you select another cell..?

Comment: One way you could solve this is to hold a selected row and assign in initially to 0. Then in assign it later on and reload the data in the table. You'd want to then modify the cellForRow to then check for that selected row instead of the hardcoded 0.

Answer (score 2):

Create a UITableViewCell xib subclass. Then you can register the same cell with different reuseIdentifiers when you're setting up your table.

```
tableView.register(CustomCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AlphaCell")
tableView.register(CustomCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "{REUSE_ID}")
```

When you setup your cell in:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

dequeue "AlphaCell" for your first cell, and "{REUSE_ID}" for your other cells.

Comment: @answered, for some projects when the content of the cell itself differs, I use exactly the very same  method you are describing here. However in this particular case it is a lot of overkill. (Downvote was not from me).